# Selenium Chrome suppress/dismiss client certificate selection dialog

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, client-certificates, ui-testing

How can I suppress or automatically dismiss the client certificate selection dialog with selenium (chrome driver)?

[image: chrome client certificate selection (german)]

I can't use this certificate, because it is stored on a chip card and I would have to enter a PIN. If no card is available, our website used a credential based login and I want to test this.

Comment: is that iframe popup OR Alert?

Comment: That's a dialog from chrome (not opened by client side code). It pops up if the website sends certain headers that signal the acceptance of client certificates. It's displayed like an alert dialog.

Comment: Can this popup be bypassed this way?

http://user:password@example.com

Comment: No. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution to this problem:
You must use chrome parameter - [AutoSelectCertificateForUrls](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoSelectCertificateForUrls)

Add this to the windows registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls\1 = "{"pattern":"https://yoursite.com","filter":{}}"
```

Answer (score 3):

In linux you need this file set:

```
$HOME/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/auto_select_certificate.json
```

With this content:

```
{
  "AutoSelectCertificateForUrls": [ "{\"pattern\":\"*\",\"filter\":{}}" ]
}
```

With this set it should allow every installed client certificate automatically.

Detailed article about how to solve it in C# with Docker can be found in an article I wrote here:
https://sgedda.medium.com/running-selenium-with-chromedriver-together-with-client-certificate-set-in-headful-mode-with-net-a79bde19e472

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch chrome using "--ignore-certificate-errors" and "--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests" arguments.

```
ChromeOptions opts = new ChromeOptions();
opts.addArguments("ignore-certificate-errors","ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opts);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
System.out.println("Title:" + driver.getTitle());
```

Comment: No it still shows the dialog :( I tried it with `ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests` and `--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests`

Comment: The funny thing is: If I add this to the command line arguments of my chrome desktop link, it is working. But not with Selenium. And for `ignore-certificate-errors` chrome says, that this is an unknown command line switch. But other parameters like `--start-maximized`are passed correctly.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe please raise an issue with chromedriver in below link: 
https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues

Comment: Sven-Michael, did you find out this problem? I need exactly the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It worked for me:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests");
webDriver = New ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can cancel this confirmation pop-up directly in Selenium by adding the following argument to ChromeOptions: "***--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests***".

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

You have to add :

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests')
```

In any case, it worked for me !